# The type or namespace name 'NativeShare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm using native share to share unity game. But i'm facing this error. How to resolve this?

Directories

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SavedGame;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
```

Native Share Code

```
    private IEnumerator TakeScreenshotAndShare()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        ss.Apply();

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.temporaryCachePath, "shared img.png");
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ss.EncodeToPNG());

        // To avoid memory leaks
        Destroy(ss);

        new NativeShare().AddFile(filePath).SetSubject("Control The Pandemic").SetText("I found this game most attractive!").Share();
    }
    public void ShareGame()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshotAndShare());
    }
```

ERROR

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NativeShare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Is NativeShare imported? Does the error show up in Unity console? Are you using Assembly Definition Files?

Comment: Yes, NativeShare is imported. No, Error doesn't appear in unity. Play Mode also works, even when I click share button `Shared! UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)` also appears in console. But NativeShare() is keep red underlined in editor and while hovering, it shows the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sol 1 - Try closing Unity, Unity HUB, VS Code and reopening it.

(Alternate) Sol 2 - After closing VS Code, try Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools -> `Regenerate project files`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add `using NativeShare` to the top of your script.

If that's not the issue and if NativeShare has its own assembly definition file, those can sometimes freak out for no reason in Unity. In that case close everything (unity visual studio etc.), delete the unity temporary folders (Libray, obj in root of your project) and open the project again.

Comment: LOL. Thanks. Closing and reopening things worked!

Comment: Error is here again. after some days without changes in that code. Now. it's not going even after reopening things